# How to get text in a specific <li> element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the text of an `<li>` element through array.

I already tried this:

```
$('#demo').text($('li').get(2));
```

But it only results:

```
[object HTMLLIElement]
```

How would I access a specific `<li>` through array?

Comment: Provide the HTML markup

Comment: I'm not sure the exact markup matters that much, although it might help to know the relationship between #demo and the li tags, e.g. is the ul id="demo"? However your attempt is obviously wrong: you need to select the element and then call `.text()` on it, rather than trying to pass an element into `.text()` (which I think means set the text on #demo to be "[object HTMLLIElement]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [:eq Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).I presume that `li` is wrap inside a `ul` element. The count starts with `0` so if you want to get the 2nd element then use:

```
$("ul li").eq(1).text();
```

OR

```
$("ul li:eq(1)").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got the paranteses wrong, try this:

```
$('#demo li').eq(2).text();
```

This will get the text of the third `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

    var items = $('#demo li');

    var liText = items.get(1).innerText;

    console.log(liText);

    // OR

    var li = $('#demo li:eq(1)');

    var liText = li.text();

    console.log(liText);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="demo">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```